# Mapbox Tileset turns blank at high zoom in Shiny using Leaflet, but not in MapBox Studio

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-studio, shiny

I uploaded a large (~8GB) geotiff to mapbox using the CLI.

```
mapbox upload bweinstein.6thBridge_03182020 6thBridge_03182020.tif
```

Everything appears fine in mapbox studio. Max Zoom is 22 and you can zoom in and see the tiles. It is the top layer in the style. Here is a fully zoomed screenshot.

[image]

In Shiny I connect the CARTO integration URL and make sure maxZoomLevels are set

```
leaflet(data=selected_centroids,options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 7, maxZoom = 22, maxNativeZoom=22)) %>% addTiles(mapbox_url)
```

Everything is fine at coarse zoom levels

[image]

but then it disappears and turns grey as you zoom.

[image]

Reading here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/blank-tiles/#style-id

```
For raster tilesets, the uploaded image resolution sets the minzoom and maxzoom levels. Higher resolution images will result in the tileset rendering at more zoom levels.

Note: regardless of maximum zoom level, data can be overzoomed and visualized to zoom 22.
```

Is this likely to be a problem in leaflet, in mapbox studio, or in shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after sitting on this for a month. Its terrible.

The original leaflet statement looks like this

```
leaflet(data=selected_centroids,options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 7, maxZoom = 22, maxNativeZoom=22)) %>% addTiles(mapbox_url)
```

Change the location of tileOptions into the addTiles function, not the leaflet function.

```
  m<-leaflet(data=selected_centroids) %>% addTiles(mapbox_url,options=tileOptions(maxZoom = 22))
```

Zoom levels are now respected. I really hope that saves someone else.